# Jedi not finding all usages in project

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme

I am using jedi via YCM in vim and an seeing some weird behavior in my project, regarding using the `usages` endpoint on the jediHttp server.  Basically it only finds a small fraction of the usages in my project of a class or function.  It does find all the usages in the current file, but does not find the vast majority in other files.  The `GoTo` command works fine and will open a new buffer anywhere in the project as expected.  However when I start at the definition and try to see all the `usages` via the `GoToReferences` command it only produces about 20% of the actual usages.

I have tried making a dummy project to recreate the behavior and it seems to have worked.  Here is the simple project structure:

```
> tree -I __pycache__
.
├── setup.py
└── test_jedi
    ├── classes.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── mod1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── recessed.py
    └── script.py

2 directories, 6 files
```

Here are the contents of those files:

classes.py

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def make_a(self):
        print('hello')
```

mod1/recessed.py:

```
from test_jedi.classes import Foo

Foo(5).make_a()
print('Ran this')
```

script.py:

```
from classes import Foo
a = Foo(5)
a.make_a()
```

Now from within vim with recessed.py in the buffer I am able to use `GoTo` on `Foo` to immediately open a `classes.py` buffer.  When I then try `GoToReferences` from the `classes.py` buffer I only get the `usages` in `script.py` and in `classes.py`.  I am at a loss to why jedi does not show me the usage in `recessed.py`

This is the quickfix buffer that shows:

```
classes.py|2 col 7| class Foo
script.py|2 col 21| from classes import Foo
script.py|5 col 5| a = Foo(5)
```

But clearly there is no reference to mod1/recessed.py which clearly has a usage of `Foo`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that this question is 1.5 years old, but for the sake of people who landed on this question like me, it's related to a currently open issue in Jedi.

Jedi `script.usages` is used by YouCompleteMe in their `GoToReferences` function. However, the `script.usages` is buggy in a lot of places, according to the author. He is very well aware of the issue, but it is low-priority as of the moment.

[Link to the issue](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/744)

Comment: Thank you for this. This was driving me nuts. I am amazed how there seem to be next to none discussions regarding this. How am I supposed to know that I should not use GoToReferences? I have probably broken someone else's code at this point and had no clue about it :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if helpful, but I see many more usages when I use the base jedi-vim plugin's "leader n" command.

Try loading both plugins like me and instead of using GoToReferences in YCM when finding usages, just use jedi-vim's find usages.